# Is it possible to use jq to sort_by then sort_by again by sub item

Tags: json, sorting, jq

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "SG": [
      {
        "Id": "17",
        "GroupName": "fistGN",
        "Permissions": [
          {
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 8080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 5080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "GroupName": "secondGN",
        "Permissions": [
          {
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 8080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 5080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to sort_by GroupName and then for each group by Permissions Port using a single command?

This is what I'm trying to do but that is not working as expected:

```
jq -s -S '.[].SG |= sort_by(.GroupName, .Permissions[].Port)' myfile.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '.[0].SG |= (map(.Permissions |= sort_by(.Port)) | sort_by(.GroupName))' myfile.json
```

- `(map(.Permissions |= sort_by(.Port)) | sort_by(.GroupName))` - compound expression to separate 2 sort operations:

  - `map(.Permissions |= sort_by(.Port))` - get a new array where each internal `.Permissions` array is sorted by key `"Port"` value
  - `sort_by(.GroupName)` - sort `SG` array items by `"GroupName"` key

---

The output:

```
[
  {
    "SG": [
      {
        "Id": "17",
        "GroupName": "fistGN",
        "Permissions": [
          {
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 5080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 8080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "GroupName": "secondGN",
        "Permissions": [
          {
            "Port": 80,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 5080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          },
          {
            "Port": 8080,
            "Protocol": "tcp"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Amazing. Would you mind educating me on each step of the solution? I'm afraid I don't understand why the map is necessary.

Comment: @douglaslps, yes, see my explanation